# Cannot find module './icon'. with angular-material2

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-material2

I have my app with 100 components in 15 modules.
It's `angular2.rc5` and `angular-cli.beta10`.

I'm upgrading to `angular-cli.beta14` but keeping `angular2.rc5` due to a dependency.

Until now everything was working but with the upgrade `angular-material2` icon started throwing errors. I only need icons and core was not loaded but just in case I tried loading that too with no success.

```js
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './icon'.
webpackContextResolve @ src:10
webpackContext  @ src:5
(anonymous function)  @ index.js:13
(anonymous function)  @ index.js:3
(anonymous function)  @ index.js:8
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7f40e89…:52
(anonymous function)  @ app.component.ts:66
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7f40e89…:52
(anonymous function)  @ version.js:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7f40e89…:52
(anonymous function)  @ main.bundle.js:134514
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 7f40e89…:52
webpackJsonpCallback  @ bootstrap 7f40e89…:23
(anonymous function)  @ main.bundle.js:1
```

If I debug at webpackContextResolve I see that the code is:

```ts
var map = {
    "app/+device/device.module": 505
};
function webpackContext(req) {
    return __webpack_require__(webpackContextResolve(req));
};
function webpackContextResolve(req) {
    var id = map[req];
    if(!(id + 1)) // check for number
        throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'.");
    return id;
};
webpackContext.keys = function webpackContextKeys() {
    return Object.keys(map);
};
webpackContext.resolve = webpackContextResolve;
module.exports = webpackContext;
webpackContext.id = 14;
```

Main module looks like this:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    [...]

    SharedModule,

    HomeModule,
    DeviceModule,
    [...]
```

DeviceModule looks like this:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    deviceRouting
  ],
```

And SharedModule like this:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ANGULAR
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    JsonpModule,

    // EXTERNAL
    MdCoreModule,
    MdIconModule,
    [...]
```

It's my first time using webpack and I don't really get why is there only one module in the map and why specifically that one.

Any advice?

**Update**

I've found where it's called. In a routes file I need to load some shared children.
in rc4, with router 3.0.0-rc1 it was like this
path: 'device',
component: DeviceComponent,

```ts
children: [
  {
    path: 'selector',
    component: DeviceSelectorComponent
  },
  ...CONTENT_DEVICE_PREVIEW_ROUTES
]
```

and in rc5, with the router 3.0.0

```ts
loadChildren: 'app/+device/device.module#DeviceModule',
```

Comment: Do you have the Icon provider (MdIconRegistry) registered in your module?

Comment: yes, It's in the main App module